# StartActivityForResult - question

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity "QueryInput" with textviews in it, which can call another activity "QueryInputHistory" with startActivityForResult.

However tje entries in the textviews of the activity "QueryInput" are not saved (to be more precised, they are deleted just before the other activity is called).

Can I somehow prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding, you would like the entries in a textView, not an editText, to persist when the user returns from QueryInputHistory back to the QueryInput activity. The text state of any editText with a valid resource ID is automagically persisted by the Android OS on a soft kill, but the text state of a textView is NOT guaranteed to be automagically persisted on a soft kill. So any non-view instance values AND any state of textView will need to be saved programmatically, perhaps in onSaveInstanceState or in onRetainConfigurationState on a soft kill and to prefs in OnStop or in onDestroy on a hard kill, if that is consistent with your requirements.

A workaround might be to use a disabled editText:

```
            if (cbProhibitEditPW.isChecked()) { // disable editing password
                editTextPassword.setFocusable(false);
                editTextPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); // user touches widget on phone with touch screen
                editTextPassword.setClickable(false); // user navigates with wheel and selects widget
                isProhibitEditPassword= true;
            }
            else { // enable editing of password
                editTextPassword.setFocusable(true);
                editTextPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                editTextPassword.setClickable(true);
                isProhibitEditPassword= false;
            }
```